# left join table, find both null and match value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two 2 table `t1(years int, numOfppl int)`, `t2(years int, numOfppl int)`.
t1 contains years between 2001 and 2010 , t2 contains years between 2003-2005 and 2007-2010

I want to query a result like that

```
t1.years   t1.numOfppl  t2.yeras   t2.numOfppl
 2001        7            null       null
 2002        6            null       null
 2003        4            2003       7
...         ...
 2006        8            null       null
 2007        4            2007        3
```

I try to query like that

```
select t1.years, t1.numOfppl, t2.years, t2.numOfppl from t1 
left join t2 on t1.years=t2.years
```

then the result could not show the null value, only start from 2003, but if i delete the  on `t1.years=t2.years` then it generate a result like cross join.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Please take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Try, instead, a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FULL OUTER JOIN`. This is the sqlfiddle. It will produce the op you are expecting
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5dd6/5)

```
select t1.years, t1.numOfppl, t2.years, t2.numOfppl from t1 
full outer join t2 on t1.years=t2.years
```

Comment: what output you getting post it and share schema and some dummy data

Comment: @PoLam see the sqlfiddle. it is dummy data. but will work